# call variables of function#1 in function#2

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures

I have my code in *mycode.js*

```
(function($) {
    function2() {
        console.log("main func: " + g_var);
    }
}(jQuery));
```

I use the code in main HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
```

```js
(function ($) {
    var g_var = 10;
    console.log("func2: " + g_var);
    function2();
}
```

but `g_var` not visible in function2

> Uncaught ReferenceError: function2 is not defined
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: g_var is not defined

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud read about declaration scopes. You would find this behavior of varibale and function scopes in nearly every programming language.

**Answer:**

To solve your problem, you have to create `function2` outside of the `IIFE`, otherwise it is only available on the inside. And then use a parameter to pass the value.

```
function function2(g_var) {
    console.log("main func: " + g_var);
}

(function() {
    var g_var = 10;
    function2(g_var);
})();
```

---

**Addition:**

If you create the variable `g_var` in the same scope as the function, you could access it on the inside of `function2` too. But I would not do that in the most cases.

There are some cases were this makes sense, like when working with callbacks, created on the inside of other functions. But on the most cases you should go with the first example and use parameters!

```
(function() {
    var g_var = 10;

    function function2() {
        console.log("main func: " + g_var);
    }

    function2();
})();
```

But really, that is not a good idea at all in the most cases! It makes sense when you think of something like this:

```
$(".foo").each(function() {
    var that = this;

    $(".bar").click(function() {
        // access 'that'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using a closure, but failing to return a public method. See this example and check the docs [MDN: JS Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
var foo = (function($) {
    function f2(g_var) { // private
        console.log("main func: " + g_var);
    }
    return {
        function2: function(g_var) {
            f2(g_var);
        }
  };   
})(jQuery);
```

and you can invoke it like this:

```
foo.function2(g_var);
```

Answer (score -1):

eisbehr is right first you need to define your func out of the IIFE then yoi should define your variable outside everything. Then you can use the variable in that js file every function and snippet.

You should write your code like this.

```
var g_var;

function function1(){
    g_var=4;
    console.log("main func: " + g_var); 
}

function function2(){
        g_var=10;
        console.log("func2: " + g_var); 
}
```